# MySQL JOIN UnIQUE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables that I need to pull records from (classifieds_items and attachments).  The images for the classified items are stored in a different table (attachments) and there can be multiple images for each classified.  I need to pull just one image for each classified item.  The problem with the statement below is it will duplicate the results with the items thas have multiple images.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM classifieds_items
          JOIN (attachments) ON (attachments.attach_rel_id = classifieds_items.item_id)
         WHERE active = 1 
           AND open = 1 
           AND date_expiry > ". time()." 
           AND attachments.attach_rel_module = 'classifieds' 
      ORDER BY RAND() 
         LIMIT 4";   

$rs = mysql_query($sql);    

if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0) {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $dtl_list .="<div class='fclass'>
                 <span class='fctitle'><a class='albumlnk' href='#'>".stripslashes($row['name']). '</a></span><br />
                 <img src="uploads/'.stripslashes($row['attach_thumb_location']).'" /><br />
                 '.stripslashes($row['price'])."
               </div>";
  }
}

echo $dtl_list;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to work on grouping the JOIN and get it somehow more proper rather then quickly use DISTINCT

Comment: If there can be multiple attachments per classified, then I would say the query is working correctly. If you only want a single record for each classified, then you can do that - but which image would you want?

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can just add `GROUP BY classifieds_items.item_id` :

```
`$sql = "SELECT *   
          FROM classifieds_items  
          JOIN (attachments) ON (attachments.attach_rel_id = classifieds_items.item_id)  
         WHERE active = 1   
           AND open = 1   
           AND date_expiry > ". time()."   
           AND attachments.attach_rel_module = 'classifieds'   
       GROUP BY classifieds_items.item_id  
      ORDER BY RAND() 
         LIMIT 4";`
```

Comment: Np. I'd expect +1 from you if it helped :)